# How to group the line in txt file to nested dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops, txt

I have a txt file that contain the data as below:

```
Id_1 1111
Member_a 2222
Member_b 3333
Member_c 4444
Device_a 5555
Device_b 6666

Id_2 1234
Member_a 5678
Member_b 1345
Device_a 3141

Id_3 1317
Member_a 5643
Member_b 4678
Member_c 4654
Member_e 4674
member_f 2314
Device_a 4433
Device_b 4354

.
.
.

and so on
```

There are 3 fields contained in each id and each field has a different number of sub-field (for example, some id has 4 members, but some have only 2 members) Is there any way that I could combine these data into something like a nested dictionary?

Here is the expected output:

```
{
 'id': 'Id_1', 
 'member': [{'Member_a': 2222}, {'Member_b': 3333}, {'Member_c': 4444}],
 'Device' : [{'Device_a': 5555}, {'Device_b': 6666}]
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: what have you tried, to read the file, split lines, save data ... ?

Comment: *"There are 3 fields contained in each id"*  why do i see more than 3 fields in each ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, "blankpaper.txt" contains the text provided from you. I have constructed dictionaries that conform to the expected output and stored each one in the list `dicts`.

In my version, I have made all strings in the final output lower case though you can adjust the code accordingly based on your needs. I was not sure if your data file sometimes had for example, `member_f`, on one line, and `Member_f` on another line, or if that was just a typo above. If similar information is known, the code can be made more efficient.

```
dicts = []

with open("blankpaper.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # if line not empty
        if (split := line.split()):
            a = split[0].lower()
            b = a[0:a.rfind('_')]
            if "id" == b:
                temp = {'id': a, 'member': [], 'device': []}
                dicts.append(temp)
            elif "member" == b:
                temp['member'].append({a: int(split[1])})
            elif "device" == b:
                temp['device'].append({a: int(split[1])})

print(dicts)
```

Output

```
[{'id': 'id_1', 'member': [{'member_a': 2222}, {'member_b': 3333}, {'member_c': 4444}], 'device': [{'device_a': 5555}, {'device_b': 6666}]}, {'id': 'id_2', 'member': [{'member_a': 5678}, {'member_b': 1345}], 'device': [{'device_a': 3141}]}, {'id': 'id_3', 'member': [{'member_a': 5643}, {'member_b': 4678}, {'member_c': 4654}, {'member_e': 4674}, {'member_f': 2314}], 'device': [{'device_a': 4433}, {'device_b': 4354}]}]
```

I hope this helps. If there are any questions or if this is not exactly what you wanted, please let me know.